# Getting a count of unique records in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MYSQL, with the fields, id, size and color. An example of the data is

```
    ID      Size     Color
    0       34       Red
    1       34       Blue
    3       38       Green
    4       36       Yellow
    5       38       Red
    6       34       Red
```

Is there a way in mysql to get the number of all unique records in the table? I.E. There are 2 records that are size 34 and red. I want to pull out the count for all unique combinations in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the count for each combination use

```
select size, color, count(*) from table group by size, color
```

Answer (score 0):

Thinking all id are unique.Try

```
Select size,color,count(*) from table group by size,color
```

Comment: I was just looking at your answer thinking that it didn't work with the id in the distinct clase. Better after the edit!

Comment: Not really sure why you didn't accept the first correct answer but glad you got your answer in the end.